# Find minimum element for the calculated decimal into the power of 2

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, binary, decimal

**There is a given array**`Int a = {3,2,0,0,1,4,5,6,0}`

**Now the every elements of array in the power of 2 as follows**

> 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^0 + 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^4 + 2^5 + 2^6 + 2^0 = 129

*Find the minimum elements required to the power of 2 so that we get same decimal value.*

129= *need to know the algorithm/function to find minimum element into the power of 2 so that we get the same decimal value which was calculated from the given array into the power of 2*.

Please let me know the function I tried it but not able to figure out as follows

**Edited **

**I want the minimum elements into the array to the power of 2. Which gives the same value.whihc was calculated from given input array**.

**what I want the binary representation of calculated decimal like as follows

> 2^7+2^0 => 128+1 => 129 so in a[] ={0,7}, two elemnts

is the possible solution. As I want minimum no's into the power of 2.

There might be a solution like

> 2^6+2^1+2^0= 129 so in a[] ={0,1,6}, three elements

but I want minimum as possible**

I take the every element of the array into the power of 2. and calculated the decimal. But not able to find the minimum elements to calculate the same decimal into the power of 2.

Comment: Can you better describe the input and the output for this algorithm? I think I have figured this out but I`m not sure without a better detailed explanation.

Comment: 129 is the answer. I want the same value with minimum elements to the array

Comment: @Dukeling: what I want the binary representation of calculated decimal like as follows

2^7+2^0 => 128+1 => 129 is the possible solution as I want minimum no's into the power of 2.  there might be a solution like 2^6+2^1+2^0= 129 

but i want minimum as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just represent result in binary, get position of ones in the binary representation

```
129dec = 10000001bin
```

so result is positions of set bits `{0,7}`

Note that you don't need binary representation itself - just extract bits positions from number

```
 IntResult = Sum Of Given Powers   //here we get value like 129
 SetBitList = {}                   //list/array for bit positions
 i = 0
 while (IntResult) do
      if (IntResult && 1)             //if least-significant bit is non-zero
           SetBitList.Add(i)  
      IntResult = IntResult >> 1                 //shift right 
      i = i + 1                                 //increment position
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants - he wants a fixed number of powers which give the minimum sum; e.g. 2 x 0 < 1 but give the same value

Comment: the sum might give overflow so you might not be able to find 129 directly

Comment: @marvel308 No language was specified, so this approach is valid for languages with arbitrary integer precision such as Python or Ruby.

Comment: @Dukeling I mean minimize the sum of the exponents themselves

Comment: @Dukeling yes his phrasing wasn't exactly precise, not helped by his grammatical errors

Comment: Thanks, @MBo this is what I want, like a function which returns a binary representation of the calculated decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot sum incase of an overflow you can use a priority queue to solve it 
basically take the 2 smallest numbers present in the priority queue currently(0 and 0) now since 2^0 + 2^0 = 2^1 we merge this and add it to the priority queue, incase the numbers were not equal we add the smaller bit to the answer and add the larger number back to the priority queue, we do this till we have exactly 1 number left in the priority queue 
Note that my priority queue is a min heap

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class priortise{
    public:
        bool operator()(const int &x, const int &y){
            return x>y;
        }
};
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int a[] = {3,2,0,0,1,4,5,6,0},ans = 0;
    //priority_queue<int, vector<int>, priortise> pq;
    priority_queue<int> pq;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        pq.push(a[i]);
    }
    while(!pq.empty()){
        int u = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        if(pq.empty()){
            ans++;
            break;
        }
        int v = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        if(u==v){
            pq.push(u+1);
        }
        else{
            ans++;
            pq.push(v);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reduce the problem to exponants all distincts. In fact if two powers of 2 have the same exponent `k`, then `2^k + 2^k = 2.2^k = 2^(k+1)` and so on...

Then according to uniqueness of base-2 representation of an integer, we can prove that the base-2 representation gives the minimum elements (all distincts).